# MediaWiki MWException - Global default '' is invalid for field stubthreshold

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

When I click on the Preferences link in our local MediaWiki (1.26.3), hosted on CentOS, I receive the following error:

```
Internal error
[fbd0dcc9] /index.php/Special:Preferences MWException from line 149 of /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/Preferences.php: Global default '' is invalid for field stubthreshold
Backtrace:

#0 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/Preferences.php(101): Preferences::loadPreferenceValues(User, RequestContext, array)
#1 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/Preferences.php(1264): Preferences::getPreferences(User, RequestContext)
#2 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/specials/SpecialPreferences.php(67): Preferences::getFormObject(User, RequestContext)
#3 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(384): SpecialPreferences->execute(NULL)
#4 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(553): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#5 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/MediaWiki.php(281): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#6 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/MediaWiki.php(714): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#7 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/includes/MediaWiki.php(508): MediaWiki->main()
#8 /var/www/mediawiki-1.26.3/index.php(41): MediaWiki->run()
#9 {main}
```

Any assistance to resolve the issue is appreciated.

Comment: Does this happen only for one user, or for all users? Do you have `$wgDefaultUserOptions` in `LocalSettings.php`? If you have, what is it set to? Do you have any extension installed that calls the [`UserGetDefaultOptions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserGetDefaultOptions) hook?

Comment: Our LocalProperties look like the following:                  $wgDefaultUserOptions = array(
        'watchcreations'                => 1,
        'watchdefault'                  => 1,
        'watchmoves'                    => 1,
        'watchdeletion'                 => 1,
        'showtoc'                                               => 1,
        'usenavigabletoc'                               => 1
);

Comment: We have only added the TreeAndMenu extension, though there appears to be the following in the list: Cite, CiteThisPage, ConfirmEdit, Gadgets, ImageMap, InputBox, Interwiki, LocalisationUpdate, Nuke, ParserFunctions, PdfHandler, Poem, Renameuser, SpamBlacklist, SyntaxHighligh_GeSHi, TitleBlackList, TreeAndMenu, WIkiEditor.

Comment: When I remove the $wgDefaultUserOptions from LocalProperties.php the error disappears. I'll keep plugging away in there to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Thank you!! Modifying how the preferences were set resolved the issue.

Comment: $wgDefaultUserOptions['<option>'] = <value>;   was the correction I needed to make!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can appear for a number of reasons, but the most common is probably an invalid or missing value in [`$wgDefaultUserOptions`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgDefaultUserOptions) in `LocalSettings.php`.

Default user settings can be changed like this:

```
$wgDefaultUserOptions['editsection'] = 0;
```

However, if you add something like this:

<s>`$wgDefaultUserOptions = array( 'editsection' => 0, 'watchdefault' => 1, 'watchmoves' => 1, ... );`</s>

while everything might seem to work just fine, as you have now overwritten the whole default array, you risk running into an error the next time a new user setting is added in the software, on a MediaWiki upgrade.

The error can also occur because of an extension that uses the [`UserGetDefaultOptions` hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/UserGetDefaultOptions) to modify default settings, or because one of the values given in `$wgDefaultUserOptions` is simply invalid.